# React Drag and Drop in Grid System

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I was trying to implement drag and drop for html grid system ( row and col arranged divisions) using react beautiful dnd.

The  code can be viewed [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-dnd-across-parent-pvkzj) ( this is forked from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5v2yvpjn7n) )

The changes i made is remove the type from droppable as I want columns also to be drop in parent container .

The problem I'm facing is that the sub item can't drag upward and drop in parent container, It can drag to downward without no issues. 
The parent container can drag up and Down